# How to implement an ENUM class for Symfony 2.7 choices like in the documentation?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, enums

When browsing the documentation for the Choice form field interface in Symfony 2.7, I keep noticing the following snippet at the [top of this page](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization):

```
$builder->add('attending', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        Status::getInstance(Status::YES),
        Status::getInstance(Status::NO),
        Status::getInstance(Status::MAYBE),
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_label' => 'displayName',
));
```

`Status` essentially implements an enum class in PHP. There seems to be no interface for that in Symfony. Does anyone know how to elegantly implement something that works like `Status` and that allows for adding more values in a single place?

Comment: sorry, I won't answer your question but I'm curious about that "flip_choices" option. I searched Symfony doc and I couldn't find anything about it. Where did you took that from ?

Comment: @VaN ``flip_choices`` was introduced as a forward-compatibility flag where the keys of the ``choices`` array serve as labels, thus allowing objects as values directly (if the array was flipped around, they would have to be keys, and objects as keys are not allowed in PHP). This will be the default for Symfony 3.0. It was introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12148). It has been renamed to the more explicit ``choices_as_values`` later, as evidenced in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization).

Answer (score 1):

```php
class Status {

    const STATUS_YES = 1;
    const STATUS_MAYBE = 2;
    const STATUS_NO = 3;

    private $enum;

    static public function getInstance($var)
    {
        return new static($var);
    }

    private function __construct($var)
    {
        $this->enum = $var;
    }

    /**
     * @returns boolean
     */
    public function is($var)
    {
        return ($this->enum == $var);
    }
}
```

If you want you can use Status as an abstract class an inherit all Status from this class and return the corresponding object

Comment: The tricky part is to have ``getInstance()`` return an object that has a ``displayName`` property. This property will be accessed by Symfony's choice field to display the label. If only PHP supported ``const`` arrays...

Answer (score 0):

With symphony, we can use annotations and doctrine care about your entity. Do not forget to call 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM'

> You should have more informations with symfony docs : http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-annotations-gets-better

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections as Collection;

/**
 * Class Person
 *
 * @package MyPackage\MyBundle\Entity
 *
 * @author Mirouf
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="t_persons")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyPackage\MyBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Person {
    const TYPE_DIVORCED = 'divorced';
    const TYPE_MARRIED = 'married';
    const TYPE_SINGLE = 'single';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"comment"="Id of the person"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=35, options={"comment"="Name of the person"})
      */

     private $number;
     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="relationshipStatus", nullable=true, options={"comment"="relationshipStatus"}, columnDefinition="ENUM('divorced', 'married', 'single')")
      */
    private $relationshipStatus;

    /** 
     * Get relationshipStatus
     *
     * @return string 
    */
    public function getRelationshipStatus()
    {
        return $this->relationshipStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Set relationshipStatus
     *
     * @param string $relationshipStatus
     *
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setRelationshipStatus($relationshipStatus)
    {
        $this->relationshipStatus = $relationshipStatus;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I don't seen this post before have the same problem so if I could help someone!